# Levels sets of a continuous function

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ is continuous. Let $A$ be the set of all maximal, connected subsets of the level set $f^{-1}(0)$. Can $A$ be uncountable?

Comment: Of course. Any compact subset of $[0,1]$ can be the zero set. You can easilly construct a function such that $f^{-1}(0)$ is the Cantor set (for example, the *distance* from the Cantor set makes the job). Moreover, your function can be smooth!